# error: ‘ostream’ does not name a type

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, operators

I am overloading the << and >> operator in C++, but it cannot compile.

The error message is :" error: ‘ostream’ does not name a type"
Why do I got this error? How to fix it?

```
#ifndef COMPLEX_H
#define COMPLEX_H
#include <cstdlib> //exit

#include <istream>
#include <ostream>

class Complex{
    public:
    Complex(void);
    Complex(double a, double b);
    Complex(double a);
    double real() const{ 
        return a;
    }

    double imag() const{
        return b;
    }
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out,const Complex& c);
    friend istream& operator>>(istream& in, Complex& c);


    private:
    double a;
    double b;
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& out,const Complex& c){
    double a=c.real() , b = c.imag();
    out << a << "+" << b<<"i";
    return out;
}

istream& operator>>(istream& in, Complex& c){
    in >> c.a>> c.b;
    return in;
}
#endif
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Use `std::ostream` and `std::istream` everywhere.

`ostream` and `istream` are in namespace `std`

Comment: Also suggested reading : [_Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?_](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/1870232) (if you accidentally end up in `using namespace std;` for your builds !

Comment: Did I overload the >> correctly?  I used this in my main.cpp: Complex c(); cin >> c; But it won't compile as well.

Comment: @user2741941 Did you use `std::istream& operator>>( std::istream& in, Complex& c ){ ... }` ?

Answer (score 7):

Us qualified names for types defined in namespace std

```
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out,const Complex& c);
```

It would be also better to include `<iostream>` instead of two separate headers `<istream>` and `<ostream>`

Answer (score 5):

You forgot to add

```
using namespace std;
```

Comment: Worth to read before using this solution: [why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)